# Convert dataframe column value from numpy.ndarray to list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a DataFrame DF like below:

| SNo | Values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `['h', 'e', 'l', 'o']` |
| 2 | `['p', 'a', 'r', 'i', 's']` |
| 3 | `['a', 'm', 'e', 'r', 'i', 'c', 'a']` |

The datatype of column 'Values' is `numpy.ndarray` when I run `type(df['Values'][0])`.

I am trying to convert the datatype of column 'Values' to 'list' to perform the below operation:

```
df[['SNo','Values']].set_index(['SNo']).apply(lambda x: ", ".join(list(x)))
```

Upon running the above, I get the error:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, numpy.ndarray found
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible input as **code** to instantiate a DataFrame?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't have ND arrays by flattening them, and use [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
df[['SNo','Values']].set_index(['SNo']).applymap(lambda x: ", ".join(x.ravel()))
```

Output:

```
                  Values
SNo                     
1             h, e, l, o
2          p, a, r, i, s
3    a, m, e, r, i, c, a
```

Or for a single column:

```
df.set_index('SNo')['Values'].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x.ravel()))
```

Output:

```
SNo
1             h, e, l, o
2          p, a, r, i, s
3    a, m, e, r, i, c, a
Name: Values, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to create a new string from the values, not `list`. Try instead:

```py
df["Values"] = df["Values"].apply(list)

print(df)
print(type(df["Values"][0]))
```

Prints:

```
   SNo                 Values
0    1           [h, e, l, o]
1    2        [p, a, r, i, s]
2    3  [a, m, e, r, i, c, a]

<class 'list'>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `numpy.char.join()` method instead of default python method for join a character to list . [document link](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.char.join.html)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'SNo': [1, 2, 3],
    'Values': [
        np.array(['h', 'e', 'l', 'o']),
        np.array(['p', 'a', 'r', 'i', 's']),
        np.array(['a', 'm', 'e', 'r', 'i', 'c', 'a'])
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df[['SNo','Values']].set_index(['SNo']).apply(lambda x: np.char.join('', x))
```

result:

| SNo | Values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | helo |
| 2 | paris |
| 3 | america |

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html).

`df.apply` applies a function along an axis (columnwise by default), so that you are effectively trying to join a Series (column "Values") containing *arrays*, which is impossible: the *iterable* passed to [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join) can only contain *strings*. Hence your `TypeError`: the first element ("sequence item 0") will be `np.array(['h', 'e', 'l', 'o'])`.

`Series.apply`, on the other hand, applies a function to the *values* inside a Series. E.g., it will use `join` on the individual *arrays*. Now, this is what we want. No need for `list` inside `join`, since your arrays are iterables too. So, simply select the column first and apply the bare `join`:

```
df[['SNo','Values']].set_index(['SNo'])['Values'].apply(', '.join)

SNo
1             h, e, l, o
2          p, a, r, i, s
3    a, m, e, r, i, c, a
Name: Values, dtype: object
```

Or if you are looking to create the actual words:

```
df[['SNo','Values']].set_index(['SNo'])['Values'].apply(''.join)

SNo
1       helo
2      paris
3    america
Name: Values, dtype: object
```

**Setup**

```
data = {'SNo': [1,2,3],
        'Values': [np.array(['h', 'e', 'l', 'o']),
                   np.array(['p', 'a', 'r', 'i', 's']),
                   np.array(['a', 'm', 'e', 'r', 'i', 'c', 'a'])]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df

   SNo                 Values
0    1           [h, e, l, o]
1    2        [p, a, r, i, s]
2    3  [a, m, e, r, i, c, a]
```